# Mongo cluster, safe reboot for secondary

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have a Mongo cluster (3 or more nodes). Realized that even quick restart of **Secondary** node affect **Primary**. We need to shutdown **Secondary** for some reason for short time. What is the best/correct procedure (with particular commands examples please)? Should we remove the node from cluster or just set it to maintenance is enough, like?:

`mongocluster:SECONDARY> db.adminCommand({"replSetMaintenance":true})`

does this command affect only one particular **Secondary** node where it was applied?

do we need to switch the particular node to hidden mode for maintenance also?
do we need to switch the particular node to delayed replica mode for maintenance also?

Comment: What do you mean by "restart of Secondary node affect Primary"? As long as the majority of all (voting) members are up the primary should not be affected.

Comment: web front app fail to connect to Primary Mongo while Secondary rebooting, not sure why.

Comment: Should not be the case. Did you connect by intention to the secondary (for read only purpose)?

Comment: As stated in the documentation here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetMaintenance/

If you want to prevent a node from servicing reads, consider using Hidden Replica Set Members instead.